# change values of several columns based on value in other column with mutate() and across()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to change the columns a and b of my initial dataframe (df) to the columns in dataframe df_new. I basically just want to set the values of column a and b to "999" if the NAvar column is NA. How is this possible with mutate and across?

```
df <- data.frame(a =1:5, b = 6:10, NAvar = c(NA, 1, 12, 4, NA))


df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(is.na(NAvar)) %>% 
  select(colnames(df)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c("a", "b"), EqualsTo=999))


df_new <- data.frame(a = c(999, 2:4, 999), b = c(999, 7:9, 999), NAvar = c(NA, 1, 12, 4, NA))

df
df_new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(a:b, ~ if_else(is.na(NAvar), 999L, .)))
#     a   b NAvar
# 1 999 999    NA
# 2   2   7     1
# 3   3   8    12
# 4   4   9     4
# 5 999 999    NA
```

Note the use of `999L` vice `999`, a numeric. If your real data ever blurs the line between `integer` and `numeric`, then `dplyr::if_else` will be problematic (for good reason). If you need to side-step that (perhaps some other calculation is inadvertently converting `a` and/or `b` to `numeric`), then some options:

```r
mutate(across(a:b, ~ if_else(is.na(NAvar), 999L, as.integer(.))))
mutate(across(a:b, ~ if_else(is.na(NAvar), 999, as.numeric(.))))

## base::ifelse
mutate(across(a:b, ~ ifelse(is.na(NAvar), 999, .)))
```

The last is taking advantage of the fact that `base::ifelse` can be perceived as *sloppy*. Realize that `ifelse(..., 1, "")` may return `numeric` or `character`, depending on the conditionals, and the fact that it is not known a priori which class will be returned is a risk. While the difference between `integer`/`numeric` is less-risky, it can still be a problem if/when other expressions require one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

using `base` R

```r
df <- data.frame(a =1:5, b = 6:10, NAvar = c(NA, 1, 12, 4, NA))
cbind(apply(df[1:2], 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(df$NAvar), 999L, x)), NAvar = df$NAvar)
#>        a   b NAvar
#> [1,] 999 999    NA
#> [2,]   2   7     1
#> [3,]   3   8    12
#> [4,]   4   9     4
#> [5,] 999 999    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

or

```r
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) ifelse(is.na(df$NAvar), 999L, x))
df
#>     a   b NAvar
#> 1 999 999    NA
#> 2   2   7     1
#> 3   3   8    12
#> 4   4   9     4
#> 5 999 999    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) `apply` is implicitly converting to a matrix; while this is not a problem if all columns are the same `class`, it does slow it down. Using `lapply(df[1:2], ...)` can be significantly faster (3x with `iris`). (2) `cbind(...)` becomes onerous when you have more than one column to bring "back"; I recommend `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], ...)` instead, as it inherently updates the data in-place and needs no changes to the other columns.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They are very helpful to me. I am new to programming